# Facebook request dialog with custom messages like Branchout

Tags: facebook, dialog, request, apprequests, fb.ui

How does Branchout custom their Request Dialog messages? There is no option for this.

The documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ doest mention any extra parameters, only app_id, redirect_uri, message   ,to , filters   , exclude_ids   , max_recipients, data, title.

As im a new user, i cant post images.. Here are the links: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tvPe.png ,

Im using the following javascript to call the facebook function:

```
FB.ui({
    method        : 'apprequests',
    message       : 'Message itself',
    title         : 'Title message',
    display       : 'iframe',
    access_token  : '(access_token)',
    to            : uids
}, function(response) {
  if (response)
  {
    // handle callback.....
    // (...)
  } 
});
```

Comment: Probably its some relationship between Branchout and Facebook: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10325921/what-feature-of-the-facebook-api-are-branchout-using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some APIs with special privileges. You have to get a way of get in touch with Facebook. I don't know any docs for it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to have special partnership to do such a thing.

Please check [Is it possible to customize the apprequest notification message similar to BranchOut?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9981798/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-apprequest-notification-message-similar-to-branc)

Comment: I've set this parameter, but this message wont appear on the user notification on the top, like Branchout. This message will only appear when you hover the mouse over the icon of the app.